How to give permission to a user in Jenkins
I have 3 views in Jenkins i.e., dev, dev-2, test. dev user should see dev and dev-2 view only.
I have tried with few optios:- project-matrix permission, role-based permission, Item role pattern(in Manage and assign roles). But All jobs are visible to dev user.
Can anyone help with this setting in Jenkins.

Set all jobs to be hidden by default and then use Views like groups and assign the jobs to them and then use the project-matrix to assign users permissions to the views(s)
